# Can I use Bayesian t-test instead of a standard frequentist t-test for small sample sizes?

Tags: bayesian, t-test

I have a very small sample of n=19 students, divided into 2 groups with n=10 (native English speakers) and n=9 (ESL speakers).

Each person in the overall sample rated their anxiety towards academic English on a scale of 1 to 5.

I want to check whether ESL speakers have lower anxiety scores than native English speakers, but the sample sizes are too small for parametric tests. My colleague told me that it's too small for non-parametric tests too. He suggested I try a Bayesian independent t-test instead (using JASP).

Would it be justified to use Bayesian statistics in this case?

Comment: 10/9 is a completely sane sample in which to apply a t-test. There is no sample too small for t-tests except 2/2 or less. The concern that the test has low power is justified. The T-test is likely the most powerful test you can do with the data you have. Bayesians don't do NHST, so I don't know what test you're referring to. But that's moot since going Bayesian doesn't exonerate you from the possible distributional assumptions that associate with small sample sizes.

Comment: @AdamO JASP is a program that has both frequentist and Bayesian methods. So they have a "Bayesian Independent Samples T-Test" which is their term for the Bayesian equivalent of a t-test. Not sure if that's the proper name for it though

Comment: My other points hold--and are probably more important--but I mention the issue of Bayesian testing because it's an open area of debate. Many approaches are out there, none are agreed upon. The option is in JASP is more a reflection of the programmers preferences; but you will have to be able to describe the test, interpret the output, and evaluate the limitations of that test. Lastly, what's the point if the test only provides approximately frequentist inference anyway?